# Number of days item present on a report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that stores daily runs of a particular report.

```
DateAdded NodeId Field1Value Field1Threshold etc
```

I now have a new requirement to list how many days NodeId has been present on the report. So if DateAdded is listed as

```
2013-03-01   <-- Run date
2013-02-28
2013-02-27
2013-02-26   <-- End of date sequence.  Return 4 days
2013-02-13
2013-01-07
```

This is also about identifying the break in the date sequence

EDIT 10:54 am my time
This is the where clause from my sp with the first suggestion

```
        t.etc,
        t.blah,
        CASE WHEN ras1.NodeId IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as AlertStat,
        fl.NodeId as fl_NodeId, 
        DATEDIFF(day, fl.LastDate, fl.FirstDate) as [DaysOn]
FROM    vwTrips t left join
        (
            select distinct nodeId 
            from    CustLogs.dbo.ReportAlertStats ras 
            where   ras.DateAdded between @RasStart and @RasEnd
        ) ras1 on  t.NodeId = ras1.NodeId left join
        (   SELECT NodeId, 
                    MIN(DateAdded) [FirstDate], 
                    MAX(DateAdded) [LastDate]
            FROM CustLogs.dbo.ReportAlertStats
            GROUP BY NodeId
            --ORDER BY NodeId, DateAdded
        ) fl on t.NodeId = fl.NodeId
WHERE   t.TripStart between @ReportStart and @ReportEnd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT fl.NodeId, DATEDIFF(day, fl.FirstDate, fl.LastDate) [Days On] FROM
(SELECT NodeId, MIN(DateAdded) [FirstDate], MAX(DateAdded) [LastDate]
FROM DailyRuns
GROUP BY NodeId
) fl
```

For NodeId that appears only once it will show the same result as if its first and last appearance happen on the same day.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea373/7

Comment: Unfortunately its not working.  It may be my fault, and this box won't let me paste what I need to

Comment: @Hecatonchires - I had typos. Please try now.  You can check it through SQL Fiddle link I provided.

Comment: Newer version looks much better, especially after I reversed the DateAdd() :)  I have a lot of **null, null** values for fl_NodeId, [Days On].  I thought they;d be eg: **6039, 1** at minimum.

Comment: @Hecatonchires Have you checked SQL_Fiddle link I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
select nodeid, count(distinct dateAdded) as NumDays
from DailyRuns dr
group by nodeid
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't account for breaks in the sequence.